# Concat function is breaking link tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, redirect, hyperlink

I could use some help on a problem that I'm having with link tracking. I need to build an email link like below, but the concat is breaking link tracking. When I send myself a test email the link works fine, but without link tracking I won't know activity. Any ideas on a workaround?

```
%%[

VAR @PromoURL

SET @PromoURL = concat("http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?rtu=$$", PromoURL, "$$")

]%%
```

`href="%%=RedirectTo(@PromoURL)=%%`

Comment: Does the link tracking work when you do a Guided Send to a test audience?

Comment: Does it work when you don't do the `concat()`? -- with just a raw URL in `@PromoURL`?

Comment: After further testing it seems that the concat isn't the issue. If I set @PromoURL to any  link value without the concat I still have the issue. It seems like the substituion of the link here %%=RedirectTo(@PromoURL)=%% is the problem. Tracking is fine when I hardcode the link directly into the email, but if I go with the approach of trying to declare and have the value populate dynamically it breaks tracking.

Comment: Is the Web Analytics Connector being used to automatically append query string params to all your URLs? When you say "Tracking is Broken", what breaks - the SFMC click redirect page or the target of the redirect? When looking at network traffic with the developer tools of your browser, where does the redirection get to?

Comment: We are not using the connector. There are no auto appends happening from anywhere. Tracking doesnt even happen. For example, if i do a guided send or send preview test, a redirect never gets generated. The link in the test email looks exactly like how its coded within the template. This happens when the tracking box is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce found the issue being that on their back end they had to activate "link wrapping" in order for the ampscript within the href to track. All fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Whats PromoURL? Is it a full link as well, like for ex 
"http://facebook.com?var1=true"?

If yes, try changing first "?"in your url to it's html equivalent

```
%%[

VAR @PromoURL

SET @PromoURL = concat("http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs&#63;rtu=$$", PromoURL, "$$")

]%%
```